# After rotation, whenever I move left or right now, it goes in the opposite direction

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

After rotation, whenever I move left or right now, it goes in the opposite direction.
Hi I'm trying to rotate my object by 90 degrees every time I press a button and it works but now when I press the right arrow, it moves left and vice versa. Can anyone help me with this? Thank you

```
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float _playerSpeed=1.5f;
    [SerializeField] private float _playerRotation = 90f;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        transform.position = new Vector2(0,8f);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float VerticalInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        float smooth = 100f;
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow))
        {
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, _playerRotation), Time.time * smooth);
            _playerRotation += 90f;
        }
        else if(horizontalInput !=0 || VerticalInput<=0)
        {
            Vector2 direction = new Vector2(horizontalInput, VerticalInput);
            transform.Translate(direction * _playerSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know Unity at all, but looking at the described behaviour: are you sure the direction of rotation is correct?  If you rotate an object by -90° instead of rotating it by 90°, then you will end up moving into opposite direction.  Are you sure the axes along which you are trying to move the object are correct?

Comment: Yes im trying to move the object in the z axis. And i tried with -90 degrees, but its the same thing

Comment: Please use the correct tags. `[unityscript]` is or better was a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in previous Unity versions and is long**deprecated** by now! Your code is clearly in `c#`

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of issues with your code.

You had:

```
// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    float horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float VerticalInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    float smooth = 100f;
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow))
    {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, _playerRotation), Time.time * smooth);
        _playerRotation += 90f;
    }
```

The first issue is that you only modify the `transform.rotation` ONCE per keypress, and that modification is only a fraction of the full intention because of the lerp.  You need to pull the lerp outside of the `if KeyDown` check.

Second issue is a little moot as resolving the first issue will also resolve the second:  You are setting `_playerRotation` *after* applying it to the transform.  There are edge cases where this is sometimes correct, but I suspect this is not one of them.

Third, the lerp factor (`Time.time * smooth`).  This is a BLEND factor and should only scale from zero to one (again, some edge cases as exceptions but this isn't one of them).  `Time.time` on its own is going to be >1 after the first second of runtime.  I expect your intention here was to animate the rotation over time, but this is done by accumulating `Time.deltaTime`.